# How to replace a certain character in Excel using VBA with incremental number?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently developing a programme with Excel VBA that allows a user to calculate certain values via input. The values entered are stored in the table and the calculated values are also displayed to the user in the table. So far I have made relatively good progress and have been able to create a dynamic table using Excel VBA. However, I am stuck on one thing and need your help.

The problem I have now are our contracts, which are also listed in the table. These contracts are initially only given a `#` when they are entered, as it is not certain how many contracts there are when they are entered. For this reason, I have only displayed the contract number as a `#` at the beginning of the programming. Now, when you have finished entering all the contracts, I would like to replace all the `#` with a number that is to be incremented (see screenshots: Before and After).

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJD3K.png) [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXNEN.png)

My code currently looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim answer As Integer
Dim answer2 As Integer
Dim answer3 As Integer
Dim vorname As String
Dim nachname As String
Dim anteil As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim sumGesamt As Integer
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim lRows As Long
Dim sumEntschaedigung As Integer
Dim sumAnteil As Integer

Set sheet = Worksheets("Ergebnis")

Set Rng = Range("A6:E1000")
sumGesamt = Rng.Find(What:="Entschädigung - Gesamt", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
sumEntschaedigung = Rng.Find(What:="####", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
sumAnteil = Rng.Find(What:="###", LookIn:=xlValues).Row

nachname = TextBox1.Value
vorname = TextBox2.Value
anteil = TextBox3.Value & " %"

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
Range("A7:E7").EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = vorname & " " & nachname
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = anteil
ActiveCell.Formula = "=C" & ActiveCell.Row & "*" & "D" & sumGesamt
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox3.Value & " (Anteil in %) x " & Range("D" & sumGesamt).Value & " (Entschädigung - Gesamt)"

Unload Eigentuemer

answer = MsgBox("Weiterer Eigentümer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Eigentümerteilung")

If answer = vbYes Then
   Eigentuemer.Show
Else
   answer2 = MsgBox("Weiterer Vertrag?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Weiterer Vertrag?")
   If answer2 = vbYes Then
    With sheet
        lr = sheet.Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("D" & sumEntschaedigung).Formula = "=Sum(D" & sumEntschaedigung + 1 & ":" & "D" & lr & ")" & "+" & "B" & sumEntschaedigung
        Range("C" & sumAnteil).Formula = "=Sum(C" & sumAnteil + 1 & ":" & "C" & lr & ")"
    End With
    Vertrag.Show
   Else
    With sheet
        lr = sheet.Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("D" & sumEntschaedigung).Formula = "=Sum(D" & sumEntschaedigung + 1 & ":" & "D" & lr & ")" & "+" & "B" & sumEntschaedigung
        Range("C" & sumAnteil).Formula = "=Sum(C" & sumAnteil + 1 & ":" & "C" & lr & ")"
    End With
    FindReplaceAll
    answer3 = MsgBox("Programm abgeschlossen! Die Datei wird automatisch gespeichert.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Entschädigungsrechner abgeschlossen")
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
End If
End Sub

Sub FindReplaceAll()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim counter As Integer

counter = counter + 1

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Cells.Replace What:="#", Replacement:=counter
Next ws

End Sub
```

As you can see I have added a new method "FindReplaceAll()" to replace current # and therefore I have used Cells.Replace. But unfortunately it doesn't work this way.

I would be very thankful if someone here could help me.

Regards

Comment: Please copy your source data from Excel (and not as an image) --; go to https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables, paste in the data (**File** -> **Paste table data...** and paste); then click **Generate** and **Copy to clipboard**; and edit the data into your question. Do the same for the expected output.

Comment: If you want to do an incremental replacing, you'll need to loop trough each `#`, not a massive replace. Maybe [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and [Range.FindNext method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) can be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the tables you posted I assume that you want to replace `#` only with word `Vertrag'. Here is a code example that does it for you. Make sure you change your ranges
and also I cannot determine the max rows in your table by screenshot so I assume the code to run for 100 rows

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()
   Dim i as Integer
   Dim counter as Integer
   counter = 1
For i = 1 to 100 Step 1
   If  Not Range("A" & i).Find("#") Is Nothing then         'Execute only if "#" was found
      Range("A" & i).Value = Replace(Range("A" & i).Value, "#", counter)
      counter = counter + 1
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried out the code you send me, but unfortunately it didn't work. I want to keep the word "Vertrag" but want to replace that "#" after this word with an incremental number (counter).

Comment: I think this answer is close, but instead of a loop from 1 to 100, consider using find initially and then find next, until you loop trough all range.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. I had to change the code a little and now it works perfectly :)

My code now looks like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim vertragBezeichnung As Integer

Set Rng = Range("A6:E1000")

vertragBezeichnung = Rng.Find(What:="Vertrag #", LookIn:=xlValues).Row

counter = 1
For i = vertragBezeichnung To 1000 Step 1
  If Not Range("A" & i).Find("#") Is Nothing Then          'Execute only if "#" was found
     Range("A" & i).Value = Replace(Range("A" & i).Value, "#", counter)
     counter = counter + 1
  End If
Next i
```